# Pages with UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uipagecontrol

I want show UITableView, but i want use it with Page Control. For example if user change page i show other data(on the same table).

I know i can change data and reload table after click on Page Control. But I want aslo change data when i scrolling horizontal and i wish it looks like i slide to other table. I don' t know how start it ?

I want sth like that(but rather with plain table): [image]

How i can start it ? Maybe there are any open source examples for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an UIScrollView with paging, look here:
http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/

Then just create an UITableView in each subview (page)

Comment: I did it. But when i add on UIScrollView my table view then app crash and i get info that i don' t have method NumbersOfSections, but i have it in my table controler.

Comment: It works when i have UITableView Delegate methods in the same controller that i have UIpageControl. If i have it in external UIViewController with table then it not works.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152857/1088519), use a `UIScrollView` that have the advantages that you can later use a nice slide animations. Take a look on the [`PanelTableView`](https://github.com/honcheng/PanelTableView) control.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this solves your problem, but any time I have wanted a UITableView to scroll horizontally instead of vertically, I have flipped it on it's side.

```
//Rotate the table 90 degrees counterclockwise
CGAffineTransform rotateTable = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
self.myTableView.transform = rotateTable;
//Code to reset the position of your table as the rotation throws it off
```

Then in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: rotate the cell

```
//Rotate the cell 90 degrees clockwise
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     ...

     CGAffineTransform rotateCell = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
     cell.transform = rotateCell;    

     return cell;
}
```

In each cell, you would put the controls that represent one "screen" or "page".  The UITableView being a UIScrollView supports paging, so you could leverage that.